# using classList to check for class in body

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to create a test that checks the body of a webpage for a particular class using vanilla JS

currently my code looks like this

```
var whole = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
whole.classList.contains("desiredClass");
```

this returns "false" on a class even though it exists in my body.

I have attempted to redefine whole as

```
var whole = document.body
```

and received the same result

Question: what is my code missing? I felt this was a pretty straightforward test, but I am certainly missing something

EDIT:

My classList function works, but was not searching for DIV classes within the body.

How do I narrow the search within the document.body to search all div classes?

Comment: `document.querySelector('body div.desiredClass')`?

Comment: Could you please also add the relevant HTML code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not good to `findElementByTagName` in this case. Using the `document.body` instead is much better.

Anyway, your code seems to be ok. Maybe it's browser compatibility issue?
Here you can see which versions of browsers supports `classList` property of DOM element: [classList doc](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp)

You can use this solution. It is much certain.

```
var classes = document.body.getAttribute('class').split(' ');
var contains = classes.indexOf('desiredClass') > -1;
```

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome. Does my code work in your browser to check for a classname?

Comment: okay I did some digging and this is what I determined. I am trying to see if div classes exist. My classlist was not working because I did not have any classes in the "body", but contained within divs in the body

Comment: It was the first thing that was needed to be checked :)